# Are MS Office usage (not programming) questions OK in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't see any Stack Exchange site for productivity applications (such as MS Office) questions. Are such questions OK in Stack Overflow?

I am thinking of questions that are not about VBA programming, such as "how can I replace all occurrences of a word by a symbol in MS Office?".

Comment: No, such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, which is clearly about programming related questions. I don't know about any SE site to recommend, but I certainly don't know all of them.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32847627/2564301) is an example-of-the-day concerning Adobe InDesign. While highly scriptable, and extensible through a dedicated SDK, the question appears to not be about either. The author's self-answer confirms this: yes, it runs on a computer and yes, InDesign is software. But the question is not about *programming*.

Comment: Where did you look?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Such questions are on topic on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) which is for questions about general/everyday computing. If its not about programming, it doesn't belong here.